# Adding a Confirmation Alert Before Publishing WordPress Posts

Tags: wordpress, confirm

I'm working on a WordPress website, and I'd like to implement a confirmation alert that appears before publishing a post. The goal is to prevent accidental publishing and allow users to confirm their intention to publish a post. I get the confirmation dialog box , but it saves the post doesn't matter if I select cancel or OK .

This is the code I am using inside functions.php

```
    function add_confirmation_script() {
        global $post_type;
        
        // Check if we're in the post editor and it's not a new post
        if ('post' === $post_type ) {
            ?>
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $(document).on('click', '.editor-post-publish-button', function(event) {
                    
                        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to publish this?')) {
                        
                            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action (post publish)
                        
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    add_action('admin_footer', 'add_confirmation_script');
```

Comment: This is already a native feature for the Gutenberg editor.